# 3d Histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a 3D histogram using python. I tried the following code but I am getting an error too many values to unpack.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy    

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

data_filename = 'C:\csvfiles\luxury.txt'

data_file = numpy.loadtxt(data_filename, delimiter=',')

X = data_file[:,1]
Y = data_file[:,2]
Z = data_file[:,3]

ax.hist(X, Y, Z)
pyplot.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

"Too many values to unpack" happens when you do something like this:

```
(a, b) = (1, 2, 3)
```

That is, not enough variables on the left to accept all of the values on the right of the `=`.

**Update:**

Try: `ax.hist( (X, Y, Z) )`

The *hist* function wants a tuple as the first argument.